# Determine bounding box of svg element from string in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, svg

If I load an SVG in chrome, I am able to get bounding box of it's elements like so:
`document.getElementById('char1').getBBox()`
->
`SVGRect {x: 348.5628356933594, y: 78.95916748046875, width: 202.74807739257812, height: 845.1696166992188}`

However if i load the same SVG using DOMParser, i get a bounding box with 0 values.

EG:

```
const svgString = document.documentElement.outerHTML // in practice this would be an svg fetched from elsewhere
let svgElement = new DOMParser().parseFromString(svgString, 'text/xml').documentElement
svgElement.getElementById('char1').getBBox()
```

->

```
SVGRect {x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0}
```

a) why does this happen?
b) how do i get the correct bounding box value by using the svg string and without loading it into the document?

Comment: Add the element(s) to the document.

Comment: I specifically cannot do that. i need to figure out the bounding box without adding the elements to the document

Comment: Why not, you can always remove them again once you're done.

Comment: Why do the elements need to be added to the document? can the bounding box not be calculated from a parsed svg element?

Comment: Only if you write all the code to do that yourself. What's the problem adding the elements, calculating the bounding box then removing them?

Comment: @RobertLongson Instead of trying to convince the person that there is no problem without knowing their project requirements, perhaps you could be helpful and explain from a spec point of view why `getBBox` is not designed to work from `DOMParser`.

Comment: @V.Rubinetti from a spec point of view there's no problem at all. From a practical point of view of getting it to work in a browser that ships today, that's where you have a problem.

Comment: Had the same problem: everything was 0. I fixed it like this: 

```
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', `<svg id="test">svg code</svg>`)
let bbox = document.getElementById("test").getBBox()
```


and then you can remove it or hide from the begin if you wish

Answer (score 0):

It isn't as pretty as it ought to be, but the solution is to temporarily add, measure, then remove it from the DOM. Because execution never returns while running these three lines of JS, the element won't actually appear on the page. Therefore, this should most likely have no side effects (unless, perhaps, you're doing something on the body with [mutation observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) or similar).

```js
const toRemove = document.body.insertAdjacentElement("beforeend", svgElement);
const bounds = svgElement.getBBox();
toRemove?.remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @Robert Longson: `getBBox()` requires your element to be appended to DOM.  Temporarily appending a svg (and eventually removing it) is usually the most convenient approach.

If you can't do this ...

#### Calculate approximated bounding box from pathData

We can get a bounding box approximation by calculating points from a pathData array

1. parse pathData via (polyfilled) [`getPathData()`](https://github.com/jarek-foksa/path-data-polyfill) method. We also use the `normalize:true` parameter to convert all commands to absolute coordinates and concert `A` (arcs) to `c` (cubic béziers)
2. loop through command array to get segment end points as well as interpolated points on curves via custom `pathDataToPolygonPoints()` helper
   [image: Exteme points]
   We need to calculate **interpolated points on curve** segments to get x/y extrema.
   The more interpolated points are calculated - the higher the accuracy.
3. loop through point array to find **min/max x and y coordinates**

```js
let svgMarkup = `<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >
    <path fill="#474bff" d="M 400 297 Q 396 362 353 402.5 Q 309 451 238.5 457 Q 176 570 137 400.5 Q 106 338 69.5 289 Q 7 236 62 186 Q 91 132 135.5 93 Q 124 12 239.5 56.5 Q 342 18 366 79.5 Q 433 100 418 170 Q 403 240 400 297 Z" />
</svg>`;

let svg = new DOMParser().parseFromString(svgMarkup, 'image/svg+xml').querySelector('svg');
let path = svg.querySelector('path');
let pathData = path.getPathData({
  normalize: true
});
// init
upDataBBox();

inputAccuracy.addEventListener('input', e => {
  upDataBBox()
})

function upDataBBox() {

  /**
   * calculate points from pathData 
   * interpolate additional points for curve segements 
   * to increase accuracy
   */
  let accuracy = +inputAccuracy.value;
  let polypoints = pathDataToPolygonPoints(pathData, true, accuracy);
  // approximated bbox
  let polyBBox = getPolygonBBox(polypoints);
  // compare with getBBox()
  let bb = pathInline.getBBox();
  let bbox = {
    x: bb.x,
    y: bb.y,
    width: bb.width,
    height: bb.height
  };

  bboxOrig.textContent = beautify(JSON.stringify(bbox));
  bboxPoly.textContent = beautify(JSON.stringify(polyBBox));

  points.innerHTML = '';
  polypoints.forEach(point => {
    renderPoint(points, point)
  })

}


function beautify(str) {
  str = str.replaceAll('{', '').replaceAll('}', '').split(',').join('\n')
  return str
}


function getPolygonBBox(polyPoints) {
  let xArr = [];
  let yArr = [];
  polyPoints.forEach(point => {
    xArr.push(point.x);
    yArr.push(point.y);
  })
  let xmin = Math.min(...xArr);
  let xmax = Math.max(...xArr);
  let ymin = Math.min(...yArr);
  let ymax = Math.max(...yArr);
  return {
    x: xmin,
    y: ymin,
    width: xmax - xmin,
    height: ymax - ymin
  }
}


/**
 * convert path d to polygon point array
 */
function pathDataToPolygonPoints(pathData, addControlPointsMid = false, splitNtimes = 0, splitLines = false) {

  let points = [];
  // close path fix
  pathData = addClosePathLineto(pathData);
  pathData.forEach((com, c) => {
    let type = com.type;
    let values = com.values;
    let valL = values.length;

    // optional splitting
    let splitStep = splitNtimes ? (0.5 / splitNtimes) : (addControlPointsMid ? 0.5 : 0);
    let split = splitStep;

    // M 
    if (c === 0) {
      let M = {
        x: pathData[0].values[valL - 2],
        y: pathData[0].values[valL - 1]
      };
      points.push(M);
    }

    if (valL && c > 0) {
      let prev = pathData[c - 1];
      let prevVal = prev.values;
      let prevValL = prevVal.length;
      let p0 = {
        x: prevVal[prevValL - 2],
        y: prevVal[prevValL - 1]
      };

      // cubic curves
      if (type === "C") {
        if (prevValL) {
          let cp1 = {
            x: values[valL - 6],
            y: values[valL - 5]
          };
          let cp2 = {
            x: values[valL - 4],
            y: values[valL - 3]
          };
          let p = {
            x: values[valL - 2],
            y: values[valL - 1]
          };

          if (addControlPointsMid && split) {
            // split cubic curves
            for (let s = 0; split < 1 && s < 9999; s++) {
              let midPoint = getPointAtCubicSegmentLength(p0, cp1, cp2, p, split);
              points.push(midPoint);
              split += splitStep
            }
          }
          points.push({
            x: values[valL - 2],
            y: values[valL - 1]
          });
        }
      }

      // quadratic curves
      else if (type === "Q") {
        if (prevValL) {
          let cp1 = {
            x: values[valL - 4],
            y: values[valL - 3]
          };
          let p = {
            x: values[valL - 2],
            y: values[valL - 1]
          };

          //let coords = prevCoords.concat(values);
          if (addControlPointsMid && split) {
            // split cubic curves
            for (let s = 0; split < 1 && s < 9999; s++) {
              let midPoint = getPointAtQuadraticSegmentLength(p0, cp1, p, split);
              points.push(midPoint);
              split += splitStep
            }
          }
          points.push({
            x: values[valL - 2],
            y: values[valL - 1]
          });
        }
      }

      // linetos
      else if (type === "L") {
        if (splitLines) {
          //let prevCoords = [prevVal[prevValL - 2], prevVal[prevValL - 1]];
          let p1 = {
            x: prevVal[prevValL - 2],
            y: prevVal[prevValL - 1]
          }
          let p2 = {
            x: values[valL - 2],
            y: values[valL - 1]
          }

          if (addControlPointsMid && split) {
            for (let s = 0; split < 1; s++) {
              let midPoint = interpolatedPoint(p1, p2, split);
              points.push(midPoint);
              split += splitStep
            }
          }
        }
        points.push({
          x: values[valL - 2],
          y: values[valL - 1]
        });
      }
    }
  });
  return points;
}


/**
 * Linear  interpolation (LERP) helper
 */
function interpolatedPoint(p1, p2, t = 0.5) {
  //t: 0.5 - point in the middle
  if (Array.isArray(p1)) {
    p1.x = p1[0];
    p1.y = p1[1];
  }
  if (Array.isArray(p2)) {
    p2.x = p2[0];
    p2.y = p2[1];
  }
  let [x, y] = [(p2.x - p1.x) * t + p1.x, (p2.y - p1.y) * t + p1.y];
  return {
    x: x,
    y: y
  };
}


/**
 * calculate single points on segments
 */

function getPointAtCubicSegmentLength(p0, cp1, cp2, p, t) {
  let t1 = 1 - t;
  return {
    x: t1 ** 3 * p0.x + 3 * t1 ** 2 * t * cp1.x + 3 * t1 * t ** 2 * cp2.x + t ** 3 * p.x,
    y: t1 ** 3 * p0.y + 3 * t1 ** 2 * t * cp1.y + 3 * t1 * t ** 2 * cp2.y + t ** 3 * p.y
  }
}

function getPointAtQuadraticSegmentLength(p0, cp1, p, t = 0.5) {
  let t1 = 1 - t;
  return {
    x: t1 * t1 * p0.x + 2 * t1 * t * cp1.x + t ** 2 * p.x,
    y: t1 * t1 * p0.y + 2 * t1 * t * cp1.y + t ** 2 * p.y
  }
}


/**
 * Add closing lineto:
 * needed for path reversing or adding points
 */

function addClosePathLineto(pathData) {
  let pathDataL = pathData.length;
  let closed = pathData[pathDataL - 1]["type"] == "Z" ? true : false;

  let M = pathData[0];
  let [x0, y0] = [M.values[0], M.values[1]];
  let lastCom = closed ? pathData[pathDataL - 2] : pathData[pathDataL - 1];
  let lastComL = lastCom.values.length;
  let [xE, yE] = [lastCom.values[lastComL - 2], lastCom.values[lastComL - 1]];
  if (closed && (x0 != xE || y0 != yE)) {
    //console.log('add final lineto')
    pathData.pop();
    pathData.push({
      type: "L",
      values: [x0, y0]
    }, {
      type: "Z",
      values: []
    });
  }
  return pathData;
}



/**
 * render point
 * accepts coordinate array and point object
 **/
function renderPoint(svg, coords, fill = "red", r = "2") {
  if (Array.isArray(coords)) {
    coords = {
      x: coords[0],
      y: coords[1]
    };
  }
  let marker = `<circle cx="${coords.x}" cy="${coords.y}" r="${r}" fill="${fill}">
      <title>${coords.x} ${coords.y}</title></circle>`;
  svg.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", marker);
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif
}

svg {
  overflow: visible;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 20em;
}

p {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<p>Accuracy: <input type="range" id="inputAccuracy" min="1" max="10" steps="1" value="1"></p>

<p><strong>BBox exact: </strong>
  <span id="bboxOrig"></span></p>
<p><strong>BBox poly:</strong>
  <span id="bboxPoly"></span></p>

<svg id="svgInline" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="36.3 40.73 385.5 461.5">
    <path id="pathInline" fill="#474bff" d="M 400 297 Q 396 362 353 402.5 Q 309 451 238.5 457 Q 176 570 137 400.5 Q 106 338 69.5 289 Q 7 236 62 186 Q 91 132 135.5 93 Q 124 12 239.5 56.5 Q 342 18 366 79.5 Q 433 100 418 170 Q 403 240 400 297 Z" />
  <g id="points"></g>
</svg>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/path-data-polyfill@1.0.4/path-data-polyfill.min.js"></script>
```

This approach works pretty well for all **geometry elements**, since `getpathData()` can also retrieve a pathData array from primitives:

- `<circle>`, `<ellipse>`,
- `<polygon>`, `<polyline>`
- `<rect>`, `<line>`

**Doesn't work for `<text>` or `<use>` elements.**