# Convert text to Svg Path to get path length - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, path

I am trying to convert text to svg to get the length of svg path. But I am getting the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: svgPath.getBBox is not a function

I tried a lot and search a lot but didn't find any solution.
If i have to insert the `SVG` element in the Html, then how can i get the `svg element` in the context api file?
The texts and svgs will be multiple.
You can check the live website here, if you need to review first:
https://uineon.hadithapi.com/
**Component:**

```
import { useCustomizer } from '../context/CustomizerContext'
export default function Preview() {
    const { settings } = useCustomizer()

    return (
        <div className="preview">
            <div className="preview-items">
                {settings.textItems.map((item, index) => (
                    <div
                        className="preview-items--item"
                        style={{
                            "--text-color": item.color
                        }}
                    >
                        <div
                            className={`preview-items--item__text ${item.backplate}`}
                            style={{
                                fontFamily: item.font,
                                fontSize: `${item.size}px`
                            }}
                        >{item.text}</div>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**Context File:**

```
import { createContext, useContext } from "react"

export const CustomizerContext = createContext()

export default function CustomizerState(props) {
    const backplateUnitPrice = 3
    const size = 30
    const backplatePrice = size * backplateUnitPrice
    const initialTextItem = {
        text: "Hello",
        font: "Raleway",
        size,
        color: "#000",
        backplate: "cut-sharp",
        uvPrint: false,
        neonPrice: 0,
        backplatePrice,
        totalPrice: 0
    }
    const [settings, setSettings] = useState({
        textItems: [initialTextItem]
    })

    const addTextItem = () => {
        textToSvg("Hello");
        const newItems = [...settings.textItems, initialTextItem]
        setSettings((prevState) => (
            {...prevState, textItems: newItems}
        ))
    }

    function textToSvg(text) {
        const svgString = `<svg viewbox="387 390 74 20"> <g> <path class="st37" d="M452,408h-56c-4.42,0-8-3.58-8-8l0,0c0-4.42,3.58-8,8-8h56c4.42,0,8,3.58,8,8l0,0 C460,404.42,456.42,408,452,408z" /> </g></svg>`
        const parser = new DOMParser();
        const parsedDoc = parser.parseFromString(svgString, "image/svg+xml");
        const parsedSvg = parsedDoc.querySelector('svg');
        const svgPath = parsedSvg.querySelector('path')
        console.log(parsedDoc)
        console.log(parsedSvg)
        console.log(svgPath)

        let bbox = svgPath.getBBox();
        let x = bbox.x + bbox.width / 2;
        let y = bbox.y + bbox.height / 2;
        
        // Create a <text> element
        let textElem = document.createElementNS(svgPath.namespaceURI, "text");
        textElem.setAttribute("x", x);
        textElem.setAttribute("y", y);
        // Centre text horizontally at x,y
        textElem.setAttribute("text-anchor", "middle");
        // Give it a class that will determine the text size, colour, etc
        textElem.classList.add("label-text");
        // Set the text
        textElem.textContent = text;
        // Add this text element directly after the label background path
        svgPath.after(textElem);
        console.log(svgPath);
    }

    return (
        <CustomizerContext.Provider value={{settings, addTextItem}}>
            {props.children}
        </CustomizerContext.Provider>
    )
}

export function useCustomizer() {
    return useContext(CustomizerContext)
}
```

I am stuck, can someone help me to achieve this?

Comment: Same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61990593/determine-bounding-box-of-svg-element-from-string-in-javascript

Comment: @MichaelMullany If i add the svg to html, then hwo can i get that element in my context  api file? I can't use `querySelector()` or something in ReactJS, right?

Comment: @Zain Shabir: please add your ReactJS code – otherwise it's hard to tell what issues you're dealing with on the react component side.

Comment: Try changing the parser type from `image/xml+svg` to `text/html`.

Comment: @herrstrietzel I have updated my question with ReactJS code, please have a look.

Comment: @tromgy It worked, but it is returning the same length if i change to text. Like If the text is `Hello`, it returns the length `162.2760009765625`, if the text is `Hello World`, it still returns the length `162.2760009765625`.

Comment: I'm not sure what "length" you're referring to, but if you want to get the length of the text's bounding box, you need to call `getBBox()` on the `<text>` element, and not the path: `textElem.getBBox()` after you populate it with the actual text.

Comment: @tromgy Have you heard about the function `getTotalLength()`? It returns the length of svg path, I need my text to convert to svg path and then I wanna get the length of path. Hope you get it.

Comment: @Zain Shabir: currently your `textToSvg()` doesn't convert any text to a svg path. The returned pathlength '16.27...' comes from your background (rounded rect) path (which won't change its's size). the `<text>` element won't return any pathLength. If you need to convert to text you will need something like [opentype.js](https://github.com/opentypejs/opentype.js) ([see this codepen](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/WNdBpoa)) – maybe you'll find a react based example.

Comment: @herrstrietzel It requires font, I don't wanna include font.

Comment: @Zain Shabir: you won't be able to get each letters path data without parsing a font file.

Answer (score 0):

You have an odd `viewBox` and `path`

If your objective is to center text over that `path`, add a `guide` path.

[image]

```html
<svg viewbox="387 390 74 20">
  <path d="M452,408h-56c-4.42,0-8-3.58-8-8l0,0c0-4.42,3.58-8,8-8h56c4.42,0,8,3.58,8,8l0,0 C460,404.42,456.42,408,452,408z"/>
  <path id="guide" d="M388 401h72" stroke="grey" pathLength="100"/>
  <text>
    <textPath href="#guide" 
              startoffset="50" text-anchor="middle" 
              dominant-baseline="middle"
              fill="gold" font-size="14px">Hello</textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: I have updated my question, please read it